# Flash Builder asset files

Tags: flash-builder

Where is the best place to store your dependent files like xml, css and assets? I have been storing them in the src folder which works ok as they get moved to the debug folder when I build.

I can't find any info on this but I'm thinking that src is not really the place for these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what it's worth, here is the way Flash Catalyst CS5 (1.0.0) organizes its packages and assets when it generates a FXP:

- src
  - (default package)
  - assets
    - graphics
    - images
  - com.adobe.flashcatalyst.components
  - components
  - skins

Where `graphics` contains any .fxg files, and `images` holds all other image files.  An auto-generated .css file (in my case, for embedding a font), was placed inside the `(default package)`.

I would assume that this is how the Adobe team would expect things to be organized.  However, you may also want to check out how they do it in Flash Catalyst "Panini", since the big thing with that release is the two-way workflow with Flash Builder "Burrito".